# How to test File-Upload functionality?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, cypress, e2e-testing

I am currently in a deep dive into Cypress and writing e2e tests for an application. I seem to have hit a road block when it comes to testing file upload functionality. Due to my beginner status as a QA engineer and the lack of Internet traffic on this specific issue I have reached and impasse. I came across [Cypres.Blob](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/blob.html#Syntax) in the Docs. Unfortunately there is not a lot of documented and I haven't been able to apply the examples to what I need to learn.

```
describe ('File Upload Test', () => {
    it('should upload a file', () => {
        let testfile = cy.fixture('../fixtures/cypresstest.txt')
        cy.get('input[type=file]').then(($input) => {
        return Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob(testfile, 'file/txt')
            .then((blob) => {
            $input.fileupload('add', { files: blob })
            })
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you have already tried? Then we can try to edit it to make it work.

Comment: Check out this repo [cypress-upload-file-post-form](https://github.com/javieraviles/cypress-upload-file-post-form) and related [issue#170](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/170) then come back with a more specific question if you have a different use-case.

Comment: I added a code snippet that must not have loaded earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue recently in a Laravel + React project, and I found an NPM module that's very useful for handling this called *cypress-file-upload.*

**USAGE**

1. NPM install cypress-file-upload
2. Import in /support/commands.js: import 'cypress-file-upload';
3. Read [cypress-file-upload Recipes](https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload/tree/a0cf1233cee799492ea0e721a5645df426814eec/recipes) for using plugin to test file uploads:

Hope this helps someone else!
Many thanks to that module's author for his work.

Answer (score 7):

I'm testing our file upload service like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('uploadFile', (fileNamePath, fileName, fileType = ' ', selector) => {
  cy.get(selector).then((subject) => {
    cy.fixture(fileNamePath, 'base64')
      .then(Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob)
      .then((blob) => {
        const el = subject[0]
        const testFile = new File([blob], fileName, {
          type: fileType,
        })
        const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
        dataTransfer.items.add(testFile)
        el.files = dataTransfer.files
      })
  })
})
```

Then in spec file. click upload button and wait for the file to load up:

```
cy.server().route('POST', api-upload-url).as('loadUp')
        cy.uploadFile('./pathToFile/' + fileName, fileName, fileType, fileInput);
        cy.get('.btn-upload.mat-raised-button.mat-primary').click()
        cy.wait('@loadUp').then((response) => {
            expect(response.method).to.eq('POST')
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
            expect(response.response.body.status).to.eq('OK')
        })
```

There's also a check for desired responses.

It's not super fancy and optimized. But it works in 3.1.5 and 3.2.0. It works using the electron 59 both headed and headless